# Parsing an MS Project 2007 xml project file

Tags: microsoft-project, microsoft-project-2007

Has anyone got any idea how to read the XML file saved by MS Project 2007? The standard binary format is .MPP but I'd like to view a project in a different viewer. I've saved the project spec as XML and the viewer I'm using needs the parent task Id for each task. Where can i find that in the rather huge amount of XML data created by ms project?

Answer (score 1):

At following location OpenProj source code is available and it can read MS project files. You need to go through the source code in order to under stand how they are parsing the xml files of MS Project.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/openproj/

Good Luck!